Is this relative interior defined dually always non-empty for closed and convex sets?
I am interested in defining a different relative interior for a closed convex set $C$ in a, possibly infinite, dimensional TVS $X$ (locally convex and Hausdorff) with topological dual $X^\ast$.
If we take the topological relative interior (interior relative to the affine hull of the set), then we run into the following problem, if $C=\prod_{n\geq 1} [0,1/n]$ (the topology is the product topology of $\prod_{n\geq 1} \mathbb R$), then it is closed but its relative interior with respect to the norm topology is empty. For this case, it feels to me that $\prod_{n\geq 1} ]0,1/n[$ would be a meaningful notion of relative interior for $C$.
The algebraic relative interior is also sometimes problematic, for instance, it can be proven that the simplex $\left\{ \{ p_n\} : 0\leq p_n, \sum_n p_n=1 \right\}$ has empty (algebraic) relative interior. In this case I would want the relative interior to be the set of $p_n$ such that $0<p_n$ for all $n$.
My approach is by using linear functional. Let $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb R$, then its relative interior is
$$
\operatorname{ri} [a,b] = \begin{cases}
\{a\}&\text{if } a=b\\
]a,b[&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, for $C$ convex and closed, define our relative interior (I do not know how to name that) to be
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{ri}(C)=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}\left(\operatorname{ri} f(C)\right)
\end{align*}
It is worth noting that by the Hahn-Banach separation theorem, since $C$ is closed, for any $x\notin C$, we can strictly separate $\{x\}$ and $C$, i.e. we can find $f\in X^\ast$ such that $f(x)\notin \overline{f(C)}$, in other-words, $x\notin f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(C)}\right)$, therefore
\begin{align*}
C=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(C)}\right)
\end{align*}
Actually for any $A\subseteq X$, the closed convex hull of $A$ is
\begin{align*}
\overline{\operatorname{conv}}(A)=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}\left(\overline{\operatorname{conv}}(f(C))\right)
\end{align*}
Where $\overline{\operatorname{conv}}$ is the closed convex hull in the reals.
Furthermore we get $\operatorname{ri}\left(\overline{C}\right)=\operatorname{ri}(C)$ which seems reasonable.
I am wondering if we can show that this relative interior is non-empty (for $C$ non-empty).
This is true for the two examples I gave above, $\left\{ \frac{1}{2n} \right\}$ is in the first one, and $\{ 2^{-n} \}$ in the second (assuming a topology that makes all $\{ p_n \}_{n\in\mathbb N} \to p_k$ continuous, for all $k$).
As an additional note, if $C$ has non-empty interior $\operatorname{int}(C)$, then by the Hahn-Banach separation theorem, this interior can be separated from any $x\notin \operatorname{int}(C)$ by some functional $f\in X^\ast$, i.e. $f(x)\notin f(\operatorname{int}(C))=\operatorname{int}( f(C))$ and so
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{int}(C)=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}(\operatorname{int}( f(C)))
\end{align*}
Note that if this is not empty, then the interior I defined is also non-empty.
If someone have references on people defining such objects, I would be very interested in reading it.

It is easy to see that the relative interior $\operatorname{ri}(C)$ is nonempty iff there exists $x\in C$ such that $f(x)\in \operatorname{ri}(f(C))$ for each $f\in X^*$.
The set $\operatorname{ri}(C)$ can be empty. For instance, let $I$ be any uncountable set. Let
$\ell_2(I)\subset\mathbb R^I$ consists of elements $x=(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ such that $$\|x\|=\left(\sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha^2\right)^{1/2}<\infty.$$ Put $X=\ell_2(I)$. Then $X$ can be considered as a linear space over the field  $\mathbb R$ endowed with the norm $\|\cdot\|$.
Put $$C=\left\{(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}: \sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha\le 1\mbox{ and } x_\alpha\ge 0\mbox{ for each }\alpha\in I\right\}.$$
It is easy to check that $C$ is a closed convex subset of $X$. Let $y=(y_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ be any point of $C$. Pick any index $\beta\in I$ such that $y_\beta=0$ and let $f:X\to\mathbb R$, $x=(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}\mapsto x_\beta$. Then $f\in X^*$, $f(C)=[0,1]$, and $f(y)=0\not\in \operatorname{ri}(f(C))$.

Amazing, this is a very intense simplex (I think it would work if $\sum_{\alpha\in I} x_{\alpha}=1$). I guess this doesn't depend much on the particular topology we use as long as all $x\to x_\beta$ are continuous as well as $x\to \sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha$ is continuous. It feels like for this particular convex set, there should not be any meaningful definition of relative interior that is non-empty.

@P.Quinton Thank you for your kind words.

I note that since we have the $\ell_2$ norm at $X$, the map $g:X\to\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto \sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha$ is discontinuous. Indeed, for each $\beta\in I$ let
$e^\beta=(e^\beta_\alpha){\alpha\in I}$ be the vector such that for each $\alpha\in I$ we have $e^\beta\alpha=1$, if $\alpha=\beta$, and $e^\beta_\alpha=0$, otherwise. Let $i:\mathbb N\to I$ be any injective map. For each natural $n$ put $x_n=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n e^{i(k)}$. Then $|x_n|=\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}$, so the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to the zero of $X$.But $g(0)=0$, whereas
$g(x_n)=1$ for each natural $n$.

I see, it makes sense. But then I don't understand why $C$ is closed, could you elaborate on that ?

@P.Quinton Sure. Let us show that the set $X\setminus C$ is open. Let $x=(x_\alpha){\alpha\in I}\in X\setminus C$ be any point. If there exists an index $\alpha\in I$ such that $x\alpha<0$ then the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $|x_\alpha|$ contains $x$ and does not intersect $C$. Otherwise, since $x\not\in C$, $\sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha>1$. Therefore there exists a finite subset $F$ of $I$ such that $S=\sum_{\alpha\in F} x_\alpha>1$. It is easy to check that the open ball centered at $x$ of radius $(S-1)/|F|$ contains $x$ and does not intersect $C$.

Thank you very much! It is now all clear.

I asked another question about this, I am now wondering if whenever $C$ is compact convex, then its relative interior as defined here is non-empty. If you have any insight on that I would be happy to hear it!
Here is the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4960236/is-this-relative-interior-defined-dually-always-non-empty-for-compact-convex-set

@P.Quinton I expect then if we weaken the topology on  $\ell_2(I)$ to the Tychonoff topology inherited from $\mathbb R^I$ then similarly to my previous comment we can show that the set $C$ will became compact
as a closed subset of the Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^I$. I expect to check this idea in details when I shall be not so tired.
