Is this relative interior defined dually always non-empty for compact convex sets?
This is a refinment of the question asked in this post. I repeat part of the setup so that it is self contained, the main difference is that I am interested in knowing if it holds for compact sets instead of closed sets.
I am interested in defining a different relative interior for a compact convex set $C$ in a, possibly infinite, dimensional TVS $X$ (locally convex and Hausdorff) with topological dual $X^\ast$.
My approach to defining the relative interior is by using linear functionals. Let $[a,b]\subseteq \mathbb R$, then its relative interior is
$$
\operatorname{ri} [a,b] = \begin{cases}
\{a\}&\text{if } a=b\\
]a,b[&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then, for any compact convex set $C$, define our relative interior (I do not know how to name that) to be
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{ri}(C)=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}\left(\operatorname{ri} f(C)\right)
\end{align*}
It is worth noting that by the Hahn-Banach separation theorem, since $C$ is closed, for any $x\notin C$, we can strictly separate $\{x\}$ and $C$, i.e. we can find $f\in X^\ast$ such that $f(x)\notin \overline{f(C)}$, in other-words, $x\notin f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(C)}\right)$, therefore
\begin{align*}
C=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}\left(\overline{f(C)}\right)
\end{align*}
Actually for any $A\subseteq X$, the closed convex hull of $A$ is
\begin{align*}
\overline{\operatorname{conv}}(A)=\bigcap_{f\in X^\ast} f^{-1}\left(\overline{\operatorname{conv}}(f(C))\right)
\end{align*}
Where $\overline{\operatorname{conv}}$ is the closed convex hull in the reals.
Furthermore we get $\operatorname{ri}\left(\overline{C}\right)=\operatorname{ri}(C)$ which seems reasonable.
I am wondering if we can show that this relative interior is non-empty (for $C$ non-empty and compact).

I compose this answer based on my answer to your prequel question.
It is easy to see that the relative interior $\operatorname{ri}(C)$ is nonempty iff there exists $x\in C$ such that $f(x)\in \operatorname{ri}(f(C))$ for each $f\in X^*$.
The set $\operatorname{ri}(C)$ can be empty. For instance, let $I$ be any uncountable set and $X$ be the vector space $\mathbb R^I$ endowed with the Tychonoff product topology. Then $X$ is a
locally convex topological vector space over the field $\mathbb R$. Moreover, for each $\alpha\in I$, the projection $\pi_\beta:X\to\mathbb R$, $x=(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}\mapsto x_\beta$ onto the $\beta$th coordinate belong to $X^*$.
Put $$C=\left\{(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}: \sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha\le 1\mbox{ and } x_\alpha\ge 0\mbox{ for each }\alpha\in I\right\}.$$
It is easy to check that $C$ is a convex subset of $X$.
Let us show that the set $X\setminus C$ is open. Let $x=(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}\in X\setminus C$ be any point. If there exists an index $\alpha\in I$ such that $x_\alpha<0$ then the set $\pi_\alpha^{-1}(-\infty,0)$ contains $x$ and does not intersect $C$. Otherwise, since $x\not\in C$, $\sum_{\alpha\in I} x_\alpha>1$. Therefore there exists a finite subset $F$ of $I$ such that $S=\sum_{\alpha\in F} x_\alpha>1$. It is easy to check that the set $\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}\pi_\alpha^{-1}(x_\alpha-(S-1)/|F|,+\infty)$ contains $x$ and does not intersect $C$.
The Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^I\subset X$ is compact by the Tychonoff theorem.
Since $C$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]^I$, $C$ is compact too.
Let $y=(y_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ be any point of $C$. Pick any index $\beta\in I$ such that $y_\beta=0$. Then $\pi_\beta(C)=[0,1]$, and $\pi_\beta(y)=0\not\in \operatorname{ri}(f(C))$.
